# Visual Studio tooling - Group solution files by specified tag

Tags: visual-studio

I was just about to add another entity to a crud system I am developing. A single entity will have several common elements in the architecture I am working with. The entity itself, nHibernate mapping, a write service, a read service, a controller, crud views (list, edit).

All these files become a bit of a pain to work with. They are in different namespaces, different assemblies and to get to them I have to wade through everything else in the solution explorer. I was thinking it would be awesome if I could tag these files (via the prop window) and then have a solution explorer-like view of the project which I could filter down to just files with a specified tag. This would make jumping around these files as I am implementing the entity a much less unpleasant experience.

Does anyone know of an existing extension that could pull this off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How About Something Like [vstags codeplex](http://vstags.codeplex.com/)

Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: Yes this looks like exactly what I wanted!